# How to remove hover over underline from css in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and CSS

I am trying using the following snippet I found on Bootsnipp.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/xaWpR

(The link has the code and preview)

I have managed to change colour and fonts the way I want but how do I remove the underline effect from the tabs?

Thank you.

Comment: Underline from `tabs` or `anchor text`? As part of suggestion, you need to add your code here for better understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `outline:none;` , this will fix your dot line issue , then use `text-decoration:none` to remove the default underline of anchor tag

```
.tabs nav li.tab-current a {
   outline:none;
}
.tabs nav a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-decoration` to `none` upon hovering the links.

```
.tabs ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always bad practice to edit the already assigned bootstrap styles.

Simply add class to your html element and edit the class.

Let's say you have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <a class="text-center custom_a"href="#">Link</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
         <a class="text-center custom_a"href="#">Link</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now some people edit the already predefined bootstrap class: `text-center`, which centers the text in the outer element, which is a really bad practice for several reasons:

- The final outputs depends on which styles will be loaded last.
- You will have to override the styles with !important, which should be avoided whenever and wherever possible.

Also you can travel through DOM:

```
ul li a {;}
```

Now imagine having several uls or lis. Then you will have to travel the DOM with [pseudo-selectors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). Traveling takes more time to match the DOM element with style parameters.

In your case simply do this:

```
.custom_a, .custom_a_hover {text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this because of remove underline for hover and focus.

```
.tabs nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.tabs nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always consider adding an explanation to it.